# Project structure design: where store toolbar icons and how access them

Tags: python, qt, pyside6

I am working on a GUI project that will contain a set of icon images. I instinctively created an `img` directory in the root project directory.

I was planning on using the root class of my application as a place to store stuff like this, and gather the `QIcon` objects in a dictionary

```
self.toolbarIcons = {QIcon("<path-to-image.png>")}
```

Then the question is how to best access these icons from several classes down the hierarchy. When I was using `tkinter` the structure was very linear as each widget was a child of its parent.

The way I have set up the `Qt` application (using `PySide6`), the base class is `QApplication`. In here I construct a `QMainWindow`, in which I set the various widgets (central widget, toolbars, statusbar, etc.).

What is a good strategy that scales well as the application complexity grows? Should I store icons relevant for a particular widget as class attributes to that particular class (and therefore spreading the icon objects throughout the code)? I like the idea of keeping the icon objects together in one spot.

I have the code separated in different directories, but basically the structure is this (MWE):

```py
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidget, QToolBar
from PySide6.QtGui import QIcon


class MyApplication(QApplication):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QApplication.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        self.icons = {'do_stuff': QIcon('<path-to-icon.png>')}
        self.mainwindow = MyMainWindow()
        self.mainwindow.show()


class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.setCentralWidget(MyCentralWidget(self))
        self.addToolBar(MyToolBar(self))


class MyCentralWidget(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        QTableWidget.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent


class MyToolBar(QToolBar):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        QToolBar.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        # How to access MyApplication.icons['do_stuff'] from here?


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApplication()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most trivial solution is that QApplication is a singleton that can be accessed in any method using the instance() method:

```py
icon = MyApplication.instance().icons["do_stuff"]
```

But I don't recommend it since a better option is to create a settings file where those properties are defined and import it:

**settings.py**

```py
ICONS = {"do_stuff": "<path-to-icon.png>"}
```

then

***.py**

```py
from settings import ICONS

# ...

icon = QIcon(ICONS["do_stuff"])
```

Comment: Ah, it is so obvious now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Qt Resource](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) system. This allows you to access any resource in the `.qrc` file using a path relative to it.

The images in the `.qrc` file are specified in filepaths relative to the directory of the `.qrc` file.
Let's say you had a project structure like this:

```
myproject/
    resources.qrc
    images/
        filename.png
    main.py
    folder/
        things.py
```

`resources.qrc`

```xml
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource>
    <file>images/filename.png</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

Then, in `main.py` you could access an image like this:

```py
icon = QIcon(":/images/filename")
```

And the access method would be the same in `folder/things.py`

```py
icon = QIcon(":/images/filename")
```